# Unable to verify that produced executable is an ARM binary with `cargo readobj`: no such subcommand

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am learning embedded Rust. I've setup the environment and am now following the [Build It instructions](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/05-led-roulette/build-it.html).

When I verify that the produced executable is an ARM binary by running the  command

```
cargo readobj --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf --bin led-roulette -- -file-headers
```

It generates an error:

```
error: no such subcommand: readobj
```

I've also tried the command

```
cargo readelf -h target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette
```

It generates the error:

```
error: no such subcommand: readelf
```

Comment: Sounds like you've missed some setup steps. `cargo readobj` is not a default subcommand (as the error message alludes). It was probably installed at some earlier step in the guide.

Comment: You may have forgotten to `cargo install cargo-binutils --vers 0.1.4` from https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/03-setup/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before running these commands, you have to install the tools as [described in chapter 3](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/03-setup/index.html).

If you did that already, then make sure you are in the `src/05-led-roulette` directory.

Comment: this is not true as of 2022. I've installed these files based on the docs and still get the error:  Below is for Ubuntu v18 and up

sudo apt-get install \
  gdb-multiarch \
  minicom \
  openocd

Answer (score 6):

The cargo package that we install by default doesn't provide the readobj subcommand, so you need to add this subcommand explicitly:

```
cargo install cargo-binutils --vers 0.1.4
```

Answer (score 5):

Most answers here suggest installing version 0.1.4 of `cargo-binutils` to fix this problem. Although this works, the recommended way is installing the latest stable version, and just after that install `llvm-tools-preview` to supply all the missing commands:

```sh
$ cargo install cargo-binutils
$ rustup component add llvm-tools-preview
```

This is documented in the [cargo-binutils crate](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-binutils).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running

`cargo readelf -h target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette`

I used:

`readelf -h target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette`

readelf is its own command, not a cargo command